# how to search for frequent occur pattern for a field

Tags: java, mysql, sql

In my Java application, if exception occurs during some request, I insert one entry for every exception line in a table with `requestId` and exception line.

Now I need to fetch most frequently occurring exceptions in descending order. i.e, exceptions which occur most of the time should be on top.

Example below.

Table:

```
requestid    exceptionline
1              java.lang.numberFormatException
1              line2
1              line3
2              java.lang.ArrayIndexoutofboundException
2              line2
2              line3
2              line4
3              java.lang.numberFormatException
3              line2
3              line3
```

So query should be such that it first matches first exceptionline for each requestid and make group, then matches second line of the exceptionline within each group . now return first_second line with number of occurrences of these two lines.

If any other better alternative available then welcome.

Comment: You might need to improve your design, if that's what your table exactly looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Better you keep  buffer values for each exceptions  and increment it on each exception call. Then you can simply call or sort the exception list with most number of buffer count